# Cannot resolve maketext() method of Toast

Tags: android

I am getting error while creating a `Toast`

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
```

I am getting cannot resolve `makeText()` method of `Toast`.

I am getting this error

```
java: no suitable method found for makeText(idtech.ESDN.ShapeData,java.lang.CharSequence,int)
    method android.widget.Toast.makeText(android.content.Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (actual argument idtech.ESDN.ShapeData cannot be converted to android.content.Context by method invocation conversion)
    method android.widget.Toast.makeText(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,int) is not applicable
      (actual argument idtech.ESDN.ShapeData cannot be converted to android.content.Context by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: Try replacing `this` with `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, text, duration).show();

Comment: I have tried it but still getting the same error

Comment: @Muneem Habib: `this` refers to what here?

Comment: First of all you missed show() method. And second thing: always post logcat output if you are facing issue

Comment: `show()` isn´t necessary, you can also call `toast.show()` later

Comment: @EgorNeliuba : your comment should be put as an answer .. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The makeText's signature is the following

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

the first paramter has to be a context object. You put `this`, but `this`  refers to this object and it can be something different from an `Activity` (a `Fragment` for instance).

Comment: I put getApplicationContext() but still i am getting same error.

Comment: text and duration what types are ? String and int?

Comment: post the exact erro do you get

Comment: what kind of class are you extending?

Answer (score 28):

***this*** in your case might not be the object of the activity. You might be using the Toast.makeText method inside you Click Listener object.
To resolve this you need to use getApplicationContext() :

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

Answer (score 9):

Have you imported the toast widget?

```
import android.widget.Toast;
```

You can also call show() in the same line if you want to output it straight away:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestion but still getting the same error

Comment: It could also be that 'this' isn't an activity, where are you trying to construct the toast? Some more code would be helpful but try getApplicationContext() instead of 'this'.

Comment: what should i write instead of this i have tried both this and also getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 7):

In the `onClick(View view)` click listener within a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` the context is retrieved with `view.getContext()`, as in:

```

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //...
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "the message", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you type:
        `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);`

Not: 
        `Toast toast = new Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);`

Answer (score 3):

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, text, duration).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, duration);`

You may also wish to append `.show()` if you want it to display

Answer (score 2):

Instead  of

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
```

Add your activity name before "this" word

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, text, duration);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of a Toast in a fragment inside a Tabbed Activity, use getContext() e.g.

`Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your Text Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to `Toast` your text in the MainActivity then do this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem in android studio, I resolve this issue by using `getActivity()` instead of `this` in the fragment

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Grab the context from the calling activity** (eg. this or MainActivity.this) and pass it into the method your Toast resides in. That way it lives together with the calling activity.

Application context, which you get from getApplicationContext() and getContext() is mainly for long running processes. Using it for short lived processes can lead to **memory leaks**.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem but in my case i found out that Xamarin c# and Java in Android studio have differences when calling some functions(same functions).

When using Xamarin and c#, then makeText becomes MakeText and show becomes Show as shown below:

```
Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(this, "Text", ToastLength.Long);
toast.Show();
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful if you are trying to use Toast in Fragment:

```
Toast.makeText(Your_Fragment_Name.super.getContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having similar issue too but

```
getContext()
```

did the trick for me

```
// If message field is empty show a toast and alert the user
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
   Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please Enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return;
}
```

Comment: so if i get you, the code was not properly formatted@stephen rauch?

Answer (score 0):

First add

```
 import android.widget.Toast;
```

statement if you did not already and then

```
Toast.makeText(YourActvityName.this, "Your Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

in the onClick  method try this

```
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it did work form me.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Blackbelt said the syntax of Toast is as follows:

```
Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Message",Toast.<specify Lenght>).show();
```

where `Activity.this` is the current activity, `Message` is the string you want to show and `Toast.length` is the length you want it to show it for.

Answer (score 0):

> assuming you are creating toast in fragment ....so use getactivity in context

assuming you are creating toast in fragment ....so use getactivity in context

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity,"Your Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using hard coded text worked fine but I had this error when I use a string from the values' resource folder, if this is your case try this:

1- Right click on the hardcoded text and extract a string resource anyway

2- undo the string resource extraction using `CTRL+Z`

3- redo the string resource extraction using `CTRL+y`

This worked for this case and the error disapeared.